# Vekone Hakol or Kone Hakol

Tags: tefilla, nusach-sefard

In the first bracha of Amida I read in a Siddur of Chaside Babov called Tefiilat Rav that in 10 days of repentence only we need to say VEkone hakol. Why?

I was aware that sepharadic custom is to. say Kone and Ashkenasic custom is to. say VEKone.

I was not aware about a link with 10 YT.

For Vechonenu Ashkenazic custom linked the Ve to ata chonantanu which is added onotsae Shabbatot, but sepharadic custom is to say this Ve everytime.

I am pretty sure that the Babov siddur is based on Tefila Yeshara (Berditshow)

In the Tfila Yeshara 2 nussachaot seem good:

1. קונה
2. וקנה
3. But no allusion to 10 Yeme Teshuva

Comment: Is this under the pretense that we always say *ve* or that we don't usually say it? I know nusach Ashkenaz says it.

Comment: The   parenthesis say that the Ve is only for 10 YT

Comment: Siddur Tefilla Yesharah (the nusah of the"Berditchever" siddur) has "ve-koneih" year-round. It has a note saying that there shouldn't be a holam malei after the kuf (a second vav). The reason is that the word needs to have the same letters as the word 've-nakei' from the 13 midot of rahamim.

Comment: Sometimes hasidic versions seem to like to put variant nusha'ot to use for specific times of year. E.g., in Birkat HaMishpat, the Koidanover siddur has 'be-tzedek u-v-mishpat be-hesed uv-rahamim' but notes to use instead 've-tzadkeinu ba-mishpat' during 10YT.

Comment: @paquda very interesting point!